# TFT LCD and PC - How to connect?

Tags: lcd, video

Having this [specification](http://lcdtech.info/download/specs/Samsung/LTN156AT05-H01.pdf), what pins must be connected to a VGA, DVI or HDMI cable?

Unfortunately i am totaly unexperienced and do not know what informations are essential for the Question. I have no trust in connecting random pins to the cable because that may kill the display or the pc (or both).

Comment: No effort. No specific information.

Comment: Is the linked specification not specific information enougth? I do not have more informations. What do you need?

Comment: Its more about not providing any information from the specification in your question. You show no attempt to solve/narrow the problem on your own, that's probably the reason why it got down-voted. The best questions are where all essential information is summarized. Its the same problem with link-only answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them. That part isn't made to interface with VGA, DVI, or HDMI; it uses LVDS. You can buy boards that will convert any or all of those to LVDS (DVI and HDMI are easier since they're already digital; VGA is harder since it's analog). With a board that outputs LVDS it's simply a matter of wiring up corresponding pins: Clk+/-, D0+/-, D1+/-, etc. The good news is that your LCD has its own backlight driver onboard, and it's 6V-20V tolerant, so you just need to give it some power and a 3.3V or 5V enable signal, no external inverter needed. It also has an I2C bus capable of providing EDID information, so you can pass that data through instead of having to program your adapter board with a correct EDID to enable a PC to detect it properly.

Comment: Oh by the way, there is a thin, welded frame around the display. Can i remove that frame to have seamless edges?

Comment: Working with an LCD that takes LVDS/pixel clock is generously an advanced project, if not highly advanced. You might want to take a step back and see if you can approach this from another direction, rather than taking it apart and making it *even harder*